# Retrieve a list of the subprocesses currently running

Tags: iphone, objective-c, subprocess

my app calls upon a couple of small programs that run simultaneously during execution in the background. i would like to get a list or array that contains the process id's of those subprocesses. how would i go about this?

Comment: How are you calling the other programs? Do you execute them yourself, or just count on them already being running?

Comment: I start them by creating an NSTask and passing a few arguments, however, in this case I would like to just count them as already running, yes.